# Reemplazar literal en .html con Unix

Tags: unix, shell-script

Tengo una serie de scripts declarados en un html con el siguiente formato xxx.jfhdskfjhdskjfhdskjfjioe3874.bundle.js. 
La parte entre los puntos, es un hash dinámico, pero que siempre será un alfanumérico con las mismas posiciones.
Mi problema es que necesito que de manera dinámica se modifique ese hash, con el de los nuevos ficheros generados, que se encuentran en el mismo directorio que el propio html.
¿Hay alguna forma limpia de hacerlo en Unix con un script?

Gracias!

Comment: ¿No has intentado nada? para cambiar el nombre de un fichero se usa el comando mv o rename y para el bucle: for filename in ./xxx.*.js; do

Comment: No necesito cambiar el nombre del fichero, necesito cambiar el contenido del fichero. mv o rename solo cambia el nombre del fichero, lo sé.

Comment: He intentado pasar con xargs la salida del ls, y luego usar el sed para reemplazar los literales, pero no he tenido resultado aun.

Comment: Entonces deberías redactar la pregunta de otra forma, porque lo que pone ahí es que quieres cambiar la parte del nombre generada con un hash y según parece, lo que quieres es cambiar el contenido de un fichero, pero ¿cuál?

Comment: Tengo un html que importa esos scripts. Y luego tengo ficheros en el mismo directorio, que se generan con ese hash de manera automática. Necesito que cuando se generen nuevos ficheros con ese hash, se modifique el contenido del html, para apuntar a esos nuevos ficheros.

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo, pero entonces no necesitas bash para cambiar la carga de los js desde el html, se puede hacer con PHP cargando los js de forma dinámica. Te pongo un ejemplo como respuesta.

Comment: Me suena que esos archivos bundle los está generando algo como webpack, y que por alguna razón ese "compilador" no está actualizando el html que utiliza los scripts, si suena que voy por buen camino la solución sería arreglar el compilador y no tirarle más tornillos al motor

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes la posibilidad de usar PHP, puedes usar esto para cargar los js de forma dinámica, en el html (cambiándolo a php):

```
<?php
    $ruta = ".";
    $filehandle = opendir($ruta);
    while($file = readdir($filehandle)) {
        if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            if(substr($file,-3) == ".js") {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='$ruta$file'></script>";
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($filehandle);
?>
```

Comment: Como comentario decir que no es muy elegante y estoy casi seguro que es inseguro o al menos, añade un vector nuevo de ataque.